# Understanding a lowpass - comb filter implementation

Tags: algorithms, control-theory, recursive-algorithms

I try to understand the implementation of the low-pass comb filter of the Freeverb reverberation algorithm:

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Lowpass_Feedback_Comb_Filter.html

The original implementation is as follows:

```
inline float comb::process(float input)
{
    float output;
    output = buffer[bufidx];
    filterstore = (output*damp2) + (filterstore*damp1);
    buffer[bufidx] = input + (filterstore*feedback);
    if(++bufidx>=bufsize) bufidx = 0;
    return output;
}
```

I drew the closed loop of this algorithm:

[image]

In the link, it says:

> Inspection of comb.h in the Freeverb source shows that Freeverb's
>   ``comb'' filter is more specifically a lowpass-feedback-comb filter
>   (LBCF4.11--§2.6.5). It is constructed using a delay line whose output
>   is lowpass-filtered and summed with the delay-line's input. The
>   particular lowpass used in Freeverb is a unity-gain one-pole lowpass
>   having the transfer function
>
> $\displaystyle H(z) = \frac{1-d}{1-d\,z^{-1}}. $
>
> When $ d=0$ , the LBCF reduces to the feedback comb filter (FBCF) of
>   §2.6.2 in which the feedback was not filtered. The overall LBCF
>   transfer function is then
>
> $ \displaystyle \hbox{LBCF}_{N}^{\,f,\,d} \;= \; \frac{z^{-N}}{1 -f\frac{1-d}{1-d\,z^{-1}}\,z^{-N}}. $

Apparently, this transfer function is implemented here. But can someone tell me, how to derive this implementation out of this transfer function?

Answer (score 1):

From the block diagram. Solving the equations

$$
\cases{
(x_n+x_f)z^{-N} = y_n\\
x_l = y_n d_2+x_l z^{-1}d_1\\
x_f = (\text{gfb})x_l
}
$$

we obtain

$$
\frac{y_n}{x_n} = \frac{z^{-N}}{1-\frac{\text{(gfb)}d_2}{1-d_1z^{-1}}z^{-N}}
$$